# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 giving a null value

Tags: angularjs, json

I know this is a duplicate but I am unable to solve this problem referring the other posts. I am very new to angular and I am trying to complete a project but am getting an error.

As I click on a button, value from `ng-model` is taken and  pushed into an array. The value here is taken as `null` instead. And for the same reason , `column` in the database that stores the value throws an error as it is getting `null` in the table column.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.addtext (scripts1.js:169)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13231), <anonymous>:4:367)
    at f (angular.js:23371)
    at b.$eval (angular.js:15878)
    at b.$apply (angular.js:15978)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23376)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Html code:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in ctrl.tasks track by $index" class ="listwrapper" id = "listwrapper">  
            <div id="titlebox">
                    <b  class ="card1" id ="cardtitle">
                        @{{task.title}}
                    </b>
            </div>

                <ul id="selected" style ="margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none;" class ="consort">
                        <li ng-click="ctrl.on($parent.$index, $index)" ng-repeat="cardt in ctrl.task.cardarr track by $index" class = "add-card" id="add-card">
                            @{{cardt}}
                        </li>   
                    </ul> 
</div>
```

The js file which includes the variable:

```
.controller('parentcontroller', ['$compile','$http', 'trelloService' , function($compile, $http, trelloService){
    'ngInject';

    var vm = this;

function addtext(parentindex,index){
        $(`#board`).sortable({
        }).disableSelection(); 
        $(`#selected`).sortable({
            connectWith: `.consort`
        }).disableSelection();
        console.log(vm.newtitle[index]);
    $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/api/card/create/"+ vm.tasks[parentindex].id ,
            data: {title: vm.newtitle[index]},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(data){
        alert("error");
    });

        var cardtitle = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.newtitle[index]));
        vm.tasks[index].cardarr.push(cardtitle);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: What is the value of `vm`, of `vm.newtitle` of `vm.newtitle[index]`, of `index`?

Comment: Could you please share your `vm.newtitle` data.

Comment: made an edit, added the html with the index and js file with controller that includes `var vm`

Comment: Please share your json

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.newtitle[index]));` this is all it is

Answer (score 0):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

There may be a two reasons for this issue :

- You are trying to access the JSON string instead of JSON object.

  parse it before accessing :

  ```
  JSON.parse(data);
  ```
- Check the Content-Type in the Response headers. It should be `application/json`.